# Logic in record the user views in PHP

Tags: php, sql, logging, optimization, record

I am working on a video viewing site and I would like to record the user view.

Instead of using third party tracking code, I would like to implement some simple record function

Right now I use the most basic way,

Add a increment view code inside the controller before the view generate:

```
$this->Playlist_model->update_playlist_view($video_id);
```

it works but can not prevent people refresh to increase the view and a harm to performance

What is the standard way to record? e.g. store the video id at the session, only update if it is not exist?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a cookie with a default value, ex. `firstTime=0`.
Set the expiration to 0 so it will expire when the browser closes.

Increment the cookie value for each refresh of the view.

Increment the counter only for the first visit.
i.e. when the cookie value is 0

In your controller

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['visitCounter']) and $_COOKIE['visitCounter']>=0){
    $_COOKIE['visitCounter']++; // increment the cookie value with 1 for each visit
}
else{
    setcookie("visitCounter", 0, 0); // if the cookie is not set or it's set and is 0, set it again
}
```

In your model

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['visitCounter']) and $_COOKIE['visitCounter']==0){
    $this->Playlist_model->update_playlist_view($video_id);
    // do your stuff only at the first visit
}
```